# Issue with Angular 2 application and select option in Internet Explorer

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, typescript, internet-explorer-11, html-select

I encountered an odd problem in Internet Explorer and I hope someone might be able to explain me the issue here.

In my Angular 2 app, I have a form with a selection box. The user can choose between different template (names). The `templates` property is an array and defined in the TypeScript component file and filled with the possible template names.

The html template looks as follows:

```
<select required [(ngModel)]="template">
    <option *ngFor="let t of templates" [ngValue]="t">{{ t }}</option>
</select>

<button type="button" [disabled]="!form1.valid" (click)="nextForm()">Next</button>
```

The whole thing works as expected (Chrome, Firefox), unless I use Internet Explorer 11 (and likely earlier). For some weird reason, I cannot select the option if there is only one available. If there are two options, it works as expected.

In Internet Explorer the following happens:

- The gui renders, at first `templates` is just defined as empty array
- My method in the TypeScript component gets the template names from my restful API and writes the result as array into `templates`
- The gui renders the option(s) as expected
- If there is only one option, it looks selected but it actually isn't. If I try to use the dropdown and select it manually, it still doesn't "really" select

I can prove that the option isn't properly selected by checking the bound model value `template` (stays null) and also `form1.valid` shows `false` (`form1` is the name of the whole form, note that the select tag is required).

The only workaround I found for IE so far is just to define

```
if (this.templates.length > 0) this.template = this.templates[0]
```

right after I successfully the array of templates. But if you ask me, this should not be necessary.

Why is IE behaving this way, and is there a better way to fix this in general?

---

**EDIT**: It does not have to do anything with the dynamic options or with the *ngFor. I tried a static example with just one option and I cannot select it in IE 11:

```
<select required [(ngModel)]="template">
    <option>Test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: did you add the script for the core-js shim?

Comment: No, but I included all the polyfills from Angular CLI's polyfills.ts: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/@angular/cli/blueprints/ng/files/__path__/polyfills.ts

Comment: Remark: This issue must be something about Internet Explorer redrawing select options after dynamic change. I know there are some other posts on StackOverflow about it, but maybe someone knows how to solve the problem for Angular specific applications.

Answer (score 1):

Although I cannot reproduce your issue with static options, we had the same problems with dynamic options if they are loaded asynchronously, see this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kHodtEPvfUAmM6ZA3lyY?p=preview).

This reason might be this unresolved [Angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14505). However, there is also a workaround that might help:

```
<form #editForm="ngForm">
    <select name="select">
        <option *ngIf="!editForm.value.select" [ngValue]="null" selected></option>
        <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option">{{option}}</option>
    </select>
</form>
```